# Is there a way to get Step Functions input values into EMR step Args

Tags: amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

We are running batch spark jobs using AWS EMR clusters. Those jobs run periodically and we would like to orchestrate those via AWS Step Functions.

As of November 2019 Step Functions has support for EMR natively. When adding a Step to the cluster we can use the following config:

```
"Some Step": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep.sync",
    "Parameters": {
        "ClusterId.$": "$.cluster.ClusterId",
        "Step": {
            "Name": "FirstStep",
            "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
            "HadoopJarStep": {
                "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
                "Args": [
                    "spark-submit",
                    "--class",
                    "com.some.package.Class",
                    "JarUri",
                    "--startDate",
                    "$.time",
                    "--daysToLookBack",
                    "$.daysToLookBack"
                ]
             }
         }
     },
     "Retry" : [
         {
             "ErrorEquals": [ "States.ALL" ],
             "IntervalSeconds": 1,
             "MaxAttempts": 1,
             "BackoffRate": 2.0
         }
     ],
     "ResultPath": "$.firstStep",
     "End": true
}
```

Within the Args List of the HadoopJarStep we would like to set arguments dynamically. e.g. if the input of the state machine execution is:

```
{
    "time": "2020-01-08",
    "daysToLookBack": 2
}
```

The strings in the config starting with "$." should be replaced accordingly when executing the State Machine, and the step on the EMR cluster should run `command-runner.jar spark-submit --class com.some.package.Class JarUri --startDate 2020-01-08 --daysToLookBack 2`. But instead it runs `command-runner.jar spark-submit --class com.some.package.Class JarUri --startDate $.time --daysToLookBack $.daysToLookBack`.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Parameters allow you to define key-value pairs, so as the value for the "Args" key is an array, you won't be able to dynamically reference a specific element in the array, you would need to reference the whole array instead. For example "Args.$": "$.Input.ArgsArray".

So for your use-case the best way to achieve this would be to add a pre-processing state, before calling this state. In the pre-processing state you can either call a Lambda function and format your input/output through code or for something as simple as adding a dynamic value to an array you can use a [Pass State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-pass-state.html) to reformat the data and then inside your task State Parameters you can use [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) to get the array which you defined in in the pre-processor. Here's an example:

```
{
"Comment": "A Hello World example of the Amazon States Language using Pass states",
"StartAt": "HardCodedInputs",
"States": {
    "HardCodedInputs": {
        "Type": "Pass",
        "Parameters": {
            "cluster": {
                "ClusterId": "ValueForClusterIdVariable"
            },
            "time": "ValueForTimeVariable",
            "daysToLookBack": "ValueFordaysToLookBackVariable"
        },
        "Next": "Pre-Process"
    },
    "Pre-Process": {
        "Type": "Pass",
        "Parameters": {
            "FormattedInputsForEmr": {
                "ClusterId.$": "$.cluster.ClusterId",
                "Args": [
                    {
                        "Arg1": "spark-submit"
                    },
                    {
                        "Arg2": "--class"
                    },
                    {
                        "Arg3": "com.some.package.Class"
                    },
                    {
                        "Arg4": "JarUri"
                    },
                    {
                        "Arg5": "--startDate"
                    },
                    {
                        "Arg6.$": "$.time"
                    },
                    {
                        "Arg7": "--daysToLookBack"
                    },
                    {
                        "Arg8.$": "$.daysToLookBack"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Next": "Some Step"
    },
    "Some Step": {
        "Type": "Pass",
        "Parameters": {
            "ClusterId.$": "$.FormattedInputsForEmr.ClusterId",
            "Step": {
                "Name": "FirstStep",
                "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
                "HadoopJarStep": {
                    "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
                    "Args.$": "$.FormattedInputsForEmr.Args[*][*]"
                }
            }
        },
        "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `States.Array()` intrinsic function. Your `Parameters` becomes:

```
  "Parameters": {
    "ClusterId.$": "$.cluster.ClusterId",
    "Step": {
      "Name": "FirstStep",
      "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
      "HadoopJarStep": {
        "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
        "Args.$": "States.Array('spark-submit', '--class', 'com.some.package.Class', 'JarUri', '--startDate', $.time, '--daysToLookBack', '$.daysToLookBack')"
      }
    }
  }
```

Intrinsic functions are documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html) but I don't think it explains the usage very well. The code snippets provided in the Step Functions console are more useful.

Note that you can also do string formatting on the args using `States.Format()`. For example, you could construct a path using an input variable as the final path segment:

```
"Args.$": "States.Array('mycommand', '--path', States.Format('my/base/path/{}', $.someInputVariable))"
```

Comment: The Step function's intrinsic-function works as expected to pass dynamic arguments. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: a qustion , can be run a cluster id was stoped with step functions

Comment: I don't know who needs to read this, but just know that any string literals you place in a `States.Array()` call need to be within SINGLE QUOTES. If you go with double quotes, you will get an unclear error message along the lines of `SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED: The value for the field '<your field>' must be a valid JSONPath`.